# /usr/bin/dpkg-split: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: linux, debian

Okay, example. Let's say someone did some stupid things, attempted to follow http://www.ewan.cc/?q=node/90 but proved himself unable to follow a simple guide.

Some errors happen along the way, and this someone tries to recover by calling apt-get upgrade. So the following happens:

```
root@srv028:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 initscripts : Depends: sysv-rc or
                        file-rc but it is not installed
 systemd : Depends: sysv-rc
           Recommends: libpam-systemd but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
root@srv028:~# apt-get upgrade -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  sysv-rc
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/82.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 128 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Preconfiguring packages ...
/usr/bin/dpkg-split: 1: /usr/bin/dpkg-split: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg exited unexpectedly
root@srv028:~#
```

How would this someone go about fixing this?

(P.S., this someone is obviously not me)

Answer (score 0):

The error is in package reconfiguration stage, and the package you're using is not the one downloaded but a cached version:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  sysv-rc
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/82.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 128 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Preconfiguring packages ...
```

Note that the system needed to get "0 bytes out of 82.8 kBytes".

My suspicion is that those 82.8 kBytes are damaged and dpkg-split chokes trying to make head or tails of (one of) them.

So, try removing the cached packages:

```
apt-get clean; apt-get autoclean
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove dpkg

   ```
   rm /usr/bin/dpkg*
   ```
2. Recompile dpkg

   ```
   wget tarball,extract && ./configure; make and install
   ```
3. Replace dpkg-*

   ```
   cp /usr/src/DPKG/bin/dpkg-* /usr/bin
   ```
4. Reinstall apt from .deb-packege

   ```
   dpkg -i apt*.deb && apt-get update; apt-get -f install
   ```

Comment: Can you provide the URL for the tarball?

Comment: http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/dpkg/